# AttributeError: 'QSlider' object has no attribute 'subtractStep'

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I am getting an error when I try to run this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'scaler_gui_3.ui'
#
# Created: Thu May 14 13:05:28 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(270, 219)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
        self.horizontalSliderFrames = QtGui.QSlider(Form)
        self.horizontalSliderFrames.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSliderFrames.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalSliderFrames"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.horizontalSliderFrames, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalScrollBarIW = QtGui.QScrollBar(Form)
        self.verticalScrollBarIW.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBarIW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalScrollBarIW"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.verticalScrollBarIW, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.labelMain = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.labelMain.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelMain"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.labelMain)
        self.horizontalScrollBarIW = QtGui.QScrollBar(Form)
        self.horizontalScrollBarIW.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBarIW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalScrollBarIW"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.horizontalScrollBarIW)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 6, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_3"))
        self.labelSmallIW = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.labelSmallIW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelSmallIW"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelSmallIW)
        self.labelBigIW = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.labelBigIW.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("labelBigIW"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.labelBigIW)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.toolButtonLoad = QtGui.QToolButton(Form)
        self.toolButtonLoad.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolButtonLoad"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.toolButtonLoad)
        self.prevButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.prevButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("prevButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.prevButton)
        self.nextButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.nextButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("nextButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.nextButton)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.checkBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("checkBox"))
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.checkBox, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.prevButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.horizontalSliderFrames.subtractStep)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.nextButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.horizontalSliderFrames.addStep)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.labelMain.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel", None))
        self.labelSmallIW.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel", None))
        self.labelBigIW.setText(_translate("Form", "TextLabel", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton", None))
        self.toolButtonLoad.setText(_translate("Form", "...", None))
        self.prevButton.setText(_translate("Form", "<", None))
        self.nextButton.setText(_translate("Form", ">", None))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "CheckBox", None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('cleanlooks')
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems like similar error happen to other people due to some "class related problems" which I have no idea about. I do not understand why it seems to work fine when I "run" in from Geany text editor, but not when I run it from terminal using python my_gui.py I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gui_template.ui.py", line 136, in <module>
    ui = Ui_Form()
  File "gui_template.ui.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.setupUi(self)
  File "gui_template.ui.py", line 89, in setupUi
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.prevButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.horizontalSliderFrames.subtractStep)
AttributeError: 'QSlider' object has no attribute 'subtractStep'
```

I also tried creating a seperate .py file in a similar fashion to how this person does it:

https://youtu.be/FcX2FsPlVeI?t=10m25s

However, I still get the same error... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addStep` and `subtractStep` slots are [deprecated members of QSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qslider-compat.html). They are only there to provide backwards compatibility with Qt3.

It seems you must be trying to run the example script using builds of Qt4/PyQt4 that do not include such deprecated APIs.

The documentation suggests using the [setValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) slot instead. But that requires passing an appropriate increment/decrement value, so it's not really a drop-in replacement (especially if you're connecting the signals via Qt Designer).

If you wanted to fix the example, you'd have to replace the two signal/slot connections with something like:

```
    def setSlider(delta):
        self.horizontalSliderFrames.setValue(
            self.horizontalSliderFrames.value() +
            delta * self.horizontalSliderFrames.singleStep())

    self.prevButton.clicked.connect(lambda: setSlider(-1))
    self.nextButton.clicked.connect(lambda: setSlider(+1))
```

Comment: Really strange! I was using Qt 4 Designer to connect my slider/button and yet it still used the old syntax...

Comment: @Vitto. Where did your Qt4/PyQt4 packages come from? I would have thought the deprecated APIs would usually be included by default (they are for me on Arch Linux).

Comment: Good question. IIRC, I just got it installed the usual way. 

sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer

But it's been a while, so I really can't say for sure.

Comment: ekhumoro, I haven't yet tried your solution, I'll let you know how it works out once I actually try it.